# Vagrant VBoxManage Error on Mac when booting a VM while executing vagrant up

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

everytime I execute vagrant up on my Mac i get the following error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "f0d41d96-6687-451e-b682-1ec409013b15", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'Block2Sem2_default_1619613054845_45024' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I tried to reinstall Vagrant and VirtualBox but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally after so much time i figured it out:

On Mac make sure you have your Security Settings set correctly.
To check go to `Security` > `Input-Monitoring` > "Accept VirtualBox". Then go to `Accessibility` > "Accept AEServer" and "VirtualBox".
Then reload your vagrant machine and everything should work.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same error while attempting to run 'vagrant up' on my Mac and this was what I did:

clicked: system preferences > Security and Privacy > unlocked Security and Privacy > Select Allow access to Oracle VirtualBox > accept the prompt to restart your Mac > upon restarting, go back to your terminal > rerun 'vagrant up'.

Hope you find this helpful.